# Extract sample of features used to build each tree in H2O

Tags: r, h2o

In GBM model, following parameters are used -

- col_sample_rate
- col_sample_rate_per_tree
- col_sample_rate_change_per_level

I understand how the sampling works and how many variables get considered for splitting at each level for every tree. I am trying to understand how many times each feature gets considered for making a decision. Is there a way to easily extract all sample of features used for making a splitting decision from the model object?

Referring to the explanation provided by H2O, http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/col_sample_rate.html, is there a way to know 60 randomly chosen features for each split?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see which features were used at a given split in a give tree you can navigate the H2OTree object.

For R see documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.getModelTree.html) and [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/H2OTree-class.html)

For Python see documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/tree.html)

You can also take a look at this [Blog](https://www.pavel.cool/machine%20learning/h2o-3/h2o-3-tree-api/) (if this link ever dies just do a google search for H2OTree class)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if I would call this easy, but the MOJO tree visualizer spits out a graphviz dot data file which is turned into a visualization.  This has the information you are interested in.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#viewing-a-mojo